# awk or shell command to count occurence of value in 1st column based on values in 4th column

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a large file with records like below :

```
jon,1,2,apple
jon,1,2,oranges
jon,1,2,pineaaple
fred,1,2,apple
tom,1,2,apple
tom,1,2,oranges
mary,1,2,apple
```

I want to find the no of person (names in col 1) have apple and oranges both. And the command should take as less memory as possible and should be fast. Any help appreciated!

Output :
awk/sed file => 2 (jon and tom)

Comment: please add the code you have tried and explain what problem you are facing with it

Comment: @Sundeep , I am pretty new to unix, so I am not sure how to do this or if it is possible at all

Comment: no problem, I was newbie too once.. I'd suggest to go through https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info (awk is better suited for this imo) , try something yourself and then ask when you face issue with code you have... see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I was going through the docs.. I found a way .. grep "apple" file | cut -d"," -f1 | sort > file1 and then grep "oranges" file | cut -d"," -f1 | sort > file2 and then comm -12 file1 file2

Comment: nice... please add that code and explanation to question :) or as an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk` is pretty easy:

```
awk -F, \
    '$4 == "apple"   { apple[$1]++  }
     $4 == "oranges" { orange[$1]++ }
     END { for (name in apple) if (orange[name]) print name }' data
```

It produces the required output on the sample `data` file:

```
jon
tom
```

Yes, you could squish all the code onto a single line, and shorten the names, and otherwise obfuscate the code.

Another way to do this avoids the `END` block:

```
awk -F, \
    '$4 == "apple"   { if (apple[$1]++ == 0 && orange[$1]) print $1 }
     $4 == "oranges" { if (orange[$1]++ == 0 && apple[$1]) print $1 }' data
```

When it encounters an `apple` entry for the first time for a given name, it checks to see if the name also (already) has an entry for `oranges` and prints it if it has; likewise and symmetrically, if it encounters an `orange` entry for the first time for a given name, it checks to see if the name also has an entry for `apple` and prints it if it has.

As noted by [Sundeep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4082052/sundeep) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49828781/awk-or-shell-command-to-count-occurence-of-value-in-1st-column-based-on-values-i/49829042#comment86673546_49829042), it could use `in`:

```
awk -F, \
    '$4 == "apple"   { if (apple[$1]++ == 0 && $1 in orange) print $1 }
     $4 == "oranges" { if (orange[$1]++ == 0 && $1 in apple) print $1 }' data
```

The first answer could also use `in` in the `END` loop.

Note that all these solutions could be embedded in a script that would accept data from standard input (a pipe or a redirected file) — they have no need to read the input file twice.  You'd replace `data` with `"$@"` to process file names if they're given, or standard input if no file names are specified.  This flexibility is worth preserving when possible.

Comment: nice.. another way is to check `if (name in orange)` which would not need the `++`

Comment: Yes, that could work too; it would have to assign a value to the elements of the arrays.  One advantage of counting (using `++`) is that it can eliminate people who have more than one "apple" or more than one "oranges" entry with minor modifications to the printing loop.

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{if($NF=="apple") a[$1]; next}
           $NF=="oranges" && ($1 in a){print $1}' ip.txt ip.txt
jon
tom
```

- This processes the input twice
- In first pass, add key to an array if last field is `apple` (`-F,` would set `,` as input field separator)
- In second pass, check if last field is `oranges` and if first field is a key of array `a`

To print only number of matches:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{if($NF=="apple") a[$1]; next}
           $NF=="oranges" && ($1 in a){c++} END{print c}' ip.txt ip.txt
2
```

Further reading: [idiomatic awk](http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/) for details on two file processing and awk idioms

Comment: Why read the file twice?  It precludes reading standard input (from a pipe, or a redirected file) when it really isn't necessary. In its favour, it does reduce the amount of memory needed.

Answer (score 1):

For the input:

```
jon,1,2,apple
jon,1,2,oranges
jon,1,2,pineaaple
fred,1,2,apple
tom,1,2,apple
tom,1,2,oranges
mary,1,2,apple
```

the command:

```
sed -n "/apple\|oranges/p" inputfile | cut -d"," -f1 | uniq -d
```

will output a list of people with both apples and oranges:

```
jon
tom
```

---

*Edit after comment*: For an for input file where lines are not ordered by 1st column and where each person can have two or more repeated fruits, like:

```
jon,1,2,apple   
fred,1,2,apple
fred,1,2,apple                                                                                                                                          
jon,1,2,oranges                                                          
jon,1,2,pineaaple                                                        
jon,1,2,oranges                                                          
tom,1,2,apple                                                            
mary,1,2,apple                                                           
tom,1,2,oranges
```

This command will work:

```
sed -n "/\(apple\|oranges\)$/ s/,.*,/,/p" inputfile | sort -u | cut -d, -f1 | uniq -d
```

Comment: -o and -E seems to be illegal option, might be not compatible with my version

Comment: I updated my answer, now with `sed` instead of `grep`.

Comment: A few issues: (1) if some name has two entries for `oranges` (and none for `apple`), you'll treat it as having one entry for `oranges` and one for `apple`, and (2) you could avoid using `cut` by using `sed` a bit harder: `sed -E -n '/,(apple|oranges)$/ s/,.*//p' | uniq -d` (a formulation which still has the "two oranges" problem) and (3) if the input data is not grouped by name (the values in column 1), you'd get bogus results — a `sort` before the `uniq -d` would work fine.

Comment: @Jonathan thanks for noting the problems with my answer. I've updated it.

Answer (score 1):

I did a work around and used only grep and comm commands.

```
grep "apple" file | cut -d"," -f1 | sort > file1
grep "orange" file | cut -d"," -f1 | sort > file2
comm -12 file1 file2 > names.having.both.apple&orange
```

comm -12 shows only the common names between the 2 files.

Solution from Jonathan also worked.

Comment: Note that this uses 7 commands — 8 if you add `rm -f file1 file2` to remove the intermediate debris.  It has to be able to read the file twice (which rules out piping the data to the script).  It isn't entirely accurate (because `henry,1,2,pineapple` and `henry,1,2,oranges` will select `henry` — you should use `grep ',apple$'`.  Also, you've changed the notation by selecting `orange` instead of `oranges`, though that's rather minor.  Since you're using Bash, you could use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) to avoid the extra files.

Comment: Arguably, you should use names generated by the `mktemp` command for the intermediate files, and add signal handling to remove the intermediate files if someone interrupts the script (`trap`).  Etc.